# Membership / subscription plugins - alternatives

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, subscription, paypal, membership

Does anyone have recommendations (backed by experience) for a membership plugin that can

- Provide for recurring subscriptions via PayPal
- Allow selected posts to be visible only to subscription members
- Allow selected posts to have come content that can be viewed by anyone, and some content that is only visible to subscription members
- Good support that recognises that the urgent support needs of payment processing not working.

I'm reasonably capable of running a Google search for alternatives - what I'm after is any actual experience (apologies if that comes across as slightly rude!)

Key requirements are reliability of the integration, informative error messaging, and support that recognises that payment processing is important and often critical.

Comment: Probably it is helpful to know which reasons are a showstopper with the YourMembers membership plugin (and please link it).

Comment: link added, reasons added - the reasons are what's needed from any payment processing plugin (IMO)

Comment: should this be a wiki-fied ? Hard to accept an answer, and there probably isn't a definitive solution?

Answer (score 2):

To be frank, my customers and I have only had miserable experiences with all of the various alternatives. Had I found a suitable one myself, I wouldn't be developing one in the background. :-P (And no, the one I'm working on by no means ready yet.)

Comment: yes, that's certainly my impression (although my experience with Your Members isn't miserable, just concerning!). Certainly be interested to hear more about your plugin as and when it's ready!

Comment: Mine will be hosted, since it won't be written using WP. The WP/Drupal plugins will stick to interfacing with the stuff I'll be hosting by offering add to cart/buy buttons on the one hand side, affiliate tracking on the other, and members-area management (within WP) where applicable. This will allow me to release new functionality (such as payment processors, etc.) without anyone needing to touch their sites.

Answer (score 1):

Please check over with the [WPMU Dev](http://premium.wpmudev.org) guys - They've got several great membership type plugins and tons of other things that can be combined to fit your needs.  They used to be a membership type site themselves but I believe just moved to a download-per-use type place.  You'd have to go check out their plugins and see if anything would fit the bill.  Good luck!

--

Edited by Denis: no affiliate links, thank you.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of the WPMU Dev plugin. The problem with this (and all the others that I'm aware of), is that you can't test it (or assess the support) without paying and then trying it out. This is why I asked for people's experience with a recommended plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PHP Purchase which is a paid wordpress plugin. I have found that not only do they provide good support but the way they programed the plugin seems very flexible compared to every other solution I tested or looked into.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Jigowatt's premium content plugin on Code Canyon.](http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-premium-content/137192)

I'm using it for a large subscription now and it's working wonderfully.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's [s2member](http://www.s2member.com/), which I've used for a while. It does what it's supposed to do, but am not a huge fan of the code. Since we used [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/) already on our sites we then switched over to using that, when the Membership and PayPal add-ons became available for it. We're really happy with that setup, but are already planning to switch from that to [Gravity Charge](http://www.gravitycharge.com/) once it's been released (am not affiliated with any of these products, btw).