# Plugin Needed (User Register - have own profile)

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I am looking for a wordpress plugin where when the user registers it creates their own profile where the user will have their own personal area.

Can anyone point to any?

Thanks

Update:

OK, I've try to explain further.

I am writting a web application which I need to plug into wordpress.

Visitors who are not logged in can use the app ... then if the user likes the application and what he/she has created, then they can register and save it and pay a monthly fee for using it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Check out http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/register-plus-redux/ ?  If not maybe clarify a bit, I'm not sure what you mean by 'their own area'

Comment: please check update

Answer (score 1):

The user automatically gets a profile page, in the form of http://example.com/author/user-name

When a user has no posts, most themes display the 404 template.

But it's perfectly possible for a theme to customise the `author.php` template to display more than just a list of posts by that user, even when the user doesn't have any posts.

If that's not enough, just use [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org).

Comment: please check update - Note: I'm trying to avoid having to use buddypress and I don't really need a social website.

Comment: You won't find a generic plugin that can interface with your custom app. You realise that, right? If you're looking for a membership plugin, see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/membership-subscription-plugins-alternatives